# Sublime Text Default Save Options

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

Why when I save a file in Sublime Text 3 is the default save location the Sublime install directory and why is the default file type nothing?

[image]

I want to set the default save location to the Desktop and the default file type to .txt, how can I do this?

Here are my settings:

```json
{
  "font_size": 9,
  "hot_exit": false,
  "ignored_packages": ["Vintage"],
  "remember_open_files": false
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't (currently) address the default extension issue, but you can also try [AdvancedNewFile](https://github.com/skuroda/Sublime-AdvancedNewFile). Rather than creating an unnamed buffer, this plugin creates a named file. The default location is configurable, though there is no default extension.

Disclaimer: I'm the maintainer of the AdvancedNewFile plugin.

**Edit**

I've updated AdvancedNewFile to support default file extensions.

Comment: Awesome! I'm at work so I can't test at the moment but I'll take your word that it works and give it a shot when I get back ^_^

Comment: Make sure you check out @dandan's answer for a modern solution that doesn't require a plugin.

Answer (score 7):

Without no line of code:

Preferences -> Settings -> paste this "default_dir": "your/favorite/path"
And you are done.

More here: https://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/settings.html#file-and-directory-settings

Answer (score 0):

You can install the [`Default File Type`](https://github.com/spadgos/sublime-DefaultFileType) plugin manually. It's a very simple plugin, and while the Package Control [page](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Default%20File%20Type) says that it's for Sublime Text 2 only, I just installed it under OSX and it works fine. To install, navigate to `%APPDATA%\Sublime Text 3\Packages` and run

```
git clone https://github.com/spadgos/sublime-DefaultFileType.git DefaultFileType
```

Then, copy `Packages\DefaultFileType\default_file_type.sublime-settings` to `Packages\User` and change its contents to the following:

```json
{
    "default_new_file_syntax": "Packages/Text/Plain text.tmLanguage",
    "use_current_file_syntax": false
}
```

Save the file, and now whenever you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to create a new file, it will be set to plain text. The plugin only works with the key combo, not via the `File -> New File` menu option.

As far as the save location goes, I have a theory, but I haven't been able to find documentation to back it up. At least on Win7 (for me), it seems like the default save location is the directory which contains the file that was open when you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> or `File -> New File` to create the new file. For example, I had my `Packages\User\Preferences.sublime-settings` file open when I created a new file, and hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> opened the Save dialog in `Packages\User`. I saved the file to the Desktop, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> for a new file, entered something, then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> and the Save dialog opened in the Desktop.

So, while there isn't a preferences setting for default save location, at least on Windows you can tweak it by always keeping a Desktop file open, then creating new files while that Desktop file is focused.

Comment: You can probably get it to work using File -> New File in ST3 if you want. You would need to utilize the `on_window_command` event listener.

Comment: I already tried this plugin, I just tried reinstalling it to make sure, but it doesn't seem to be working on Windows 8 x64 with Sublime Text 3. It's strange as the file always says "Plain Text" in the bottom right but it never actually appends the .txt to the file name.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a built-in option, honestly, but it seems fairly simple to automate yourself. Hit Tools -> New Plugin

Then paste this over the file that's created, hit save and call it "DefaultLanguage.py" or something:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class EverythingIsPowerShell(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
   def on_new(self, view):
      view.set_syntax_file('Packages/PowerShell/Support/PowershellSyntax.tmLanguage')
```

Of course, you can change the language from PowerShell to ... whatever you prefer.  You just need the relative path to the tmLanguage.  You can get that by opening a file in your favorite language and then open the console (View->Show Console) and type:

```
view.settings().get('syntax')
```