# How to save a Plain Text file in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: macos, sublimetext3, sublimetext, executable, plaintext

I have Sublime Text 3 and I have OSX 10.10.4

Whenever I open ST3 and create a Plain Text it actually creates an executable.

Is there a way to make the file created by ST3 not executable by default?

Comment: How are you creating that file exactly?

Comment: I open ST3 click new file, set syntax to plain text or check on the lower right corner if it is already selected and write some text, save it and I have an executable

Comment: There is no such thing as *my text editor saves files as executable*. There is such thing as *my OS thinks a file is executable*. Just change the default program that you use for opening files with that extension to Sublime.

Comment: @ndn Thanks but ST3 is not adding any extension to the file, should I be the one adding? when I create a new file and set its syntax to python and then save it I get the .py extension for free, not the case in plain text, Moreover I changed the default application that opens that file and now ST3 indeed opens it with the double click but still the icon is executable

Comment: In addition to that I just created another plain text file with Sublime Text and it still shows an executable icon and opens terminal when I oduble click it (Even though I just set ST3 as the default opening app for the previou file)

Comment: @NunoCalaim, basically what you are asking here is *how do I make OSX not assume files without extensions are executable*. I haven't used OSX, but I would guess even if there is a way, it is a bad idea. There are probably a lot executables already saved with no extension. Please remove the Sublime tags.

Comment: Ok I can do that, but then my problem is still unsolved, what should be the ideal behavior of sublime when just saving a plain text, adding the extension automatically?

Comment: Does ST make the file executable (`chmod +x`)? If not, then it's really pretty much just an issue of OS X associating files without extension with the terminal.

Comment: @deceze  and ndn thanks for the help but now I see that the problem is even weirder, if I save the file with sublime in the desktop everything works as expected, the problem was that I was saving it on a vera crypt volume! Maybe I should erase this question and ask why the different behavior for that type of volume

Comment: About the default file extension - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18672029/sublime-text-default-save-options